# Deformation of projective bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, deformation-theory, fibre-bundles, flatness

Let $\pi:\mathcal{X} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a flat, projective family of noetherian schemes with generic fiber a smooth, projective variety. Let $p:\mathcal{Y} \to \mathcal{X}$ be another flat, projective family such that the composed morphism $\pi \circ p:\mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{P}^1$ satisfies the property that for a general $t \in \mathbb{P}^1$, $\mathcal{Y}_t:=(\pi \circ p)^{-1}(t)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathcal{X}_t}$, where $\mathcal{X}_t:=\pi^{-1}(t)$.

Does this imply that for *any* point $t \in \mathbb{P}^1$,$\mathcal{Y}_t \cong \mathbb{P}^2_{\mathcal{X}_t}$? If not true in general, is there any known condition under which this holds?

Any idea/reference in this direction will be very helpful.

Comment: That is not true.  Let $\mathcal{X}$ be  $X_0\times \mathbb{P}^1$ for a projective scheme $X_0$.  Let $p:\mathcal{Y}\to \mathcal{X}$ be the projective bundle associated to a locally free sheaf $\mathcal{E}$ on $X_0\times \mathbb{P}^1$ that arises from a pencil of extensions $0\to K\to E \to Q\to 0$, where $K$ and $Q$ are fixed locally free sheaves on $X_0$, where the generic such extension has $E\cong \mathcal{O}_{X_0}^{\oplus 3}$, but where $K\oplus Q$ is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{X_0}^{\oplus 3}$.

Comment: For instance, if $X_0$ equals $\mathbb{P}^2$, then you can use the twisted Euler sequence, $0\to \Omega_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}^{\oplus 3} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)\to 0.$

Comment: Another example: take $X = P^1$ and let $Y$ be the blowup of $X \times P^2$ at one point. Of course, it is flat over $X$, but its special fiber is a union of two components.